# How to convert rows to columns and query on them in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables **Patients** table: which contains the name of my patients, **Controls** table: which represents the UI controls which could be drawn for each illness , and **ControlsValues** table which contains the values of the controls submitted for each Patient

Lets have some data **Patients** Table

```
|ID  | Name |
|-----------|
| 1  | Ara  |
| 2  | Sada |
```

**Controls** table

```
|ID  | Text | Type     |
|-----------|----------|
| 1  | age  | textbox  |
| 2  |alergy| checkbox |
```

Then the controlsValues table which is where I want to query at

```
|ID  | contrlId | value    | patientId |
|---------------|----------|-----------|
| 1  | 1        | 23       | 1         |
| 2  | 2        | true     | 1         |
| 3  | 1        | 26       | 2         |
| 4  | 2        | false    | 2         |
```

here my problem occurs when I want to return that patient from ControlsValues table that has the `(controlId=1 AND value=23) and (controlId=2 AND value=true)` in this case the condition is on two rows not two columns which it is not possible , so I desided to change the rows into the columns depending on controlId but I dont know how and I have been searching for 2 days and seen a lot of samples but none of them helped me to solve my problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A way to solve the problem is with subqueries

```
select patientId from controlValues 
where controlId=1 AND value=23 
and patientId in (
    select patientId 
    from controlValues 
    where controlId=2 and value=true
)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
    select * from controlvalues;

    +----+----------+-------+-----------+
    | id | contrlId | value | patientId |
    +----+----------+-------+-----------+
    |  1 |        1 | 23    |         1 |
    |  2 |        2 | true  |         1 |
    |  3 |        1 | 26    |         2 |
    |  4 |        2 | false |         2 |
    |  5 |        1 | 23    |         3 |
    |  6 |        2 | true  |         3 |
    +----+----------+-------+-----------+
    6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

mysql> SELECT cv1.patientId p1,cv1.contrlId ctrl1, cv1.value val1,cv2.patientId p2,cv2.contrlId ctrl2, cv2.value val2 
    FROM  controlvalues cv1 , controlvalues cv2 
    WHERE cv1.patientId = cv2.patientId and cv1.contrlId = 2 and cv1.value = 'true' and cv2.contrlId = 1  and cv2.value = '23';

```
+------+-------+------+------+-------+------+
| p1   | ctrl1 | val1 | p2   | ctrl2 | val2 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------+------+
|    1 |     2 | true |    1 |     1 | 23   |
|    3 |     2 | true |    3 |     1 | 23   |
+------+-------+------+------+-------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is also working , but if I want to make the third condition , I should make another join in order to make the query

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following (I'll ignore the other tables for now):

```
CREATE TABLE pcv
(patient_id INT NOT NULL
,control_id INT NOT NULL
,value    VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(patient_id,control_id)
);

INSERT INTO pcv VALUES
(1,1,'23'),
(1,2,'true'), 
(2,1,'26'),
(2,2,'false');

SELECT * FROM pcv;
+------------+------------+-------+
| patient_id | control_id | value |
+------------+------------+-------+
|          1 |          1 | 23    |
|          1 |          2 | true  |
|          2 |          1 | 26    |
|          2 |          2 | false |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

There are two standard solutions. The first is slower but simpler to write:

Solution 1:

```
SELECT patient_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN control_id = 1 THEN value END) age
     , MAX(CASE WHEN control_id = 2 THEN value END) allergy
  FROM pcv
 GROUP
    BY patient_id;
+------------+------+---------+
| patient_id | age  | allergy |
+------------+------+---------+
|          1 | 23   | true    |
|          2 | 26   | false   |
+------------+------+---------+
```

Solution 2:

```
SELECT pcv1.patient_id
     , pcv1.value age
     , pcv2.value allergy 
  FROM pcv pcv1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN pcv pcv2 
    ON pcv2.patient_id = pcv1.patient_id 
   AND pcv2.control_id = 2 
 WHERE pcv1.control_id = 1;
+------------+-----+---------+
| patient_id | age | allergy |
+------------+-----+---------+
|          1 | 23  | true    |
|          2 | 26  | false   |
+------------+-----+---------+
```

Note that when adopting an EAV model, it's still good practice to utilise proper data types where possible. So you might have a table that stores date information, and another that stores string information.

Comment: Your solution seems more advanced but I do not know the name of my controls to query on the names it is dynamic , and it changes per user, that is about your first solution , the second one is closer from what I wanted

Comment: Either way, that's just a JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to count the rows that match if you need to be sure they meet more than your set number of criteria - after all, you may have more than one match! If you want to get sophisticated, set a variable that has the minimum number of records they need to match and go from there.

```
SELECT  P.ID, P.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM    Patients    P
JOIN    ControlsValues  V ON V.patientId = P.ID
WHERE   (V.value = 23 AND V.ControlId = 1)
OR  (V.value = 'true' AND V.ControlId = 2)
GROUP BY P.ID, P.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can represent your rows as columns by join.

```
select
    *
from controlsValues cv1
join controlsValues cv2
    on cv1.patientId = cv2.patientId
    and cv1.id <> cv2.id -- remove duplicates
where
    cv1.contrlId = 1 AND cv1.value = 23
    and cv2.contrlId = 2 AND cv2.value = 'true'
;
```

Now you can see your patients who 23 years old and has alergy.

Comment: this is also works fine , but if the query was on more than two rows it becomes a bit maze , thanks

Comment: It's becomes obvious when you will give clever names to tables, for example: `select * from controlsValues as age` than `age.value = 23` and etc...

Comment: If you about `and cv1.id <> cv2.id -- remove duplicates` you can reach it in another way: `select * from cv1 where cv1.contrlId = 1` than `join cv2 on cv2.contrlId = 2`.